# Firebase: Event Property Data not shown in Firebase

Tags: firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am sending some custom properties to firebase when I trigger an event but they do not appear in Firebase.

I have enabled the debug view and the data does arrive perfectly fine in the debug stream.

Debug View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mImAj.jpg

Analytics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cArrJ.jpg

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: Did you set up custom parameter reporting? https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489

Comment: How long have you waited? DebugView can show data within 1 minute but aggregated data will appear on the dashboard within 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem but after a few days, my custom parameters now have values. It's so strange but after 4 days, all the custom parameters suddenly have values and everything works just fine!